# Trying to make a basic TCP client in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, tcp

I am trying to implement a basic TCP client in WPF. I have managed to to this using windows forms but can't get it working in WPF. I have tried going back to the very basics and adding things bit by bit. This is to connect to an arduino that is outputing single lines of code. I can successfully connect to it through telnet so the problem is with my code.

This is what I have so far:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private TcpClient tcp;
    private StreamWriter SwSender;
    private StreamReader SrReciever;
    private Thread thrMessaging;
    private delegate void UpdateLogCallBack(string strMessage);

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btn_Connect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TcpClient tcp = new TcpClient();
        txt_Log.AppendText("connecting");
        tcp.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.137.1"), 2000);
        txt_Log.AppendText("Connected");
        thrMessaging = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ReceiveMessages));
        thrMessaging.Start();

    }
    private void ReceiveMessages()
    {
        SrReciever = new StreamReader(tcp.GetStream());
        while (true)
        {
            string response = SrReciever.ReadLine();
            txt_Log.Dispatcher.Invoke(new UpdateLogCallBack(this.UpdateLog), new object[] { response });
        }
    }
    private void UpdateLog(string strMessage)
    {
        txt_Log.AppendText(strMessage);
    }
}
```

}

Running this gives me an error in the Receive messages method. It says the error is on the line with "SrReciever = new StreamReader(tcp.GetStream());" saying it a NullReferenceException, Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I'm not the best at programming, so if there is an example out there for a TCP client that works in WPF then that will be very helpful.

Thanks
Nick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is simply because you're creating a scoped variable here:

```
private void btn_Connect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //TcpClient tcp = new TcpClient();
    //this initialized a new tcp variable only here...

    //do this instead...
    tcp = new TcpClient();
    //this will assign a new TcpClient to MainWindow.tcp
```

So what happens is `MainWindow.tcp` is actually null and then when `ReceiveMessages` is called  you are trying to call GetStream a null value.